# Erro ORA-00922 na criação de tabela no apex 5

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela no apex5 com referência, possuindo chave estrangeira de uma outra tabela e que essa coluna de chave estrangeira seja populada. Mas ao criar está retornando o erro:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Já verifiquei e não constatei nenhum erro de nomeclatura o que pode está dando errado? Segue o código:

```
    CREATE TABLE  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" 
   (    "COD" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COD_SISTEMA" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOME" VARCHAR2(55), 
    "ARQUIVO_IMAGEM" BLOB, 
    "MIMETYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "IMG_LAST_UPDATE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(55), 
    "TEXTO_DESCRICAO" VARCHAR2(55), 
    "LINK" VARCHAR2(2000), 
    "NUM_ORDEM" NUMBER(6,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COD") USING INDEX ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ADD CONSTRAINT "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COD_SISTEMA")
      REFERENCES  "APEX_SISTEMA" ("COD") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
/


CREATE INDEX  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA_I2" ON  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ("COD_SISTEMA")
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BI_IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" 
  before insert or update on IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :new.COD is null then
     select to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') into :new.cod from dual;
  end if; 
  if inserting then
       :new.img_last_update := localtimestamp;
       :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
  elsif updating and :new.filename is not null and nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(:new.arquivo_imagem),0) > 15728640 then
       raise_application_error(-20000, 'O tamanho do arquivo enviado foi maior do que 15MB . Faça o upload de um arquivo de tamanho menor.');
  end if;
  if (inserting or updating) and :new.filename is not null and nvl(:new.mimetype,'NULL') not like 'image%' then
       raise_application_error(-20000, 'O arquivo enviado não é uma imagem. Faça o upload de um arquivo de imagem.');
  end if;
  if inserting or updating then
       :new.img_last_update := localtimestamp;
       :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
  end if;
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_TB_DOC_IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ENABLE
/
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Oracle?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Olá. Consegui resolver o problema. O problema é que no apex os comandos devem ser dados um a um. Comando a comando foi compilando. Mas tive o mesmo erro ocorrendo ao compilar a trigger, mas consegui localizar o problema. O problema da trigger era por causa da palavra chave EDITIONABLE, sem ela compilou sem problemas e a trigger foi criada também. Agradeço a quem tentou ajudar.

Comment: Pensei que vc estava querendo utilizar o EDITIONABLE  que está na documentação do 12c, claro ai deveria ser `EDITIONING`, mas não cheguei a ler a fundo, segue -> (https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2#editionable_objects)